# Firebase Database network stubbing advice

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm starting out a new project on iOS with Firebase Realtime Database. All looks good expect we have an 'offline-mode' functionality for the debug version which will essentially return stubbed data whenever we make a network call.

Previously I have done this with OHHTTPStubs, but I don't know if it will fit this use case.

Does firebase use NSURLSession under the hood? and has anybody got any advice if I should use the traditional stubbing approach here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Database has built-in support for such offline behavior. It will automatically work when your app has intermittently lost network connectivity. In addition it can be configured to store its cached data (and queued writes) on the local disk, so that it survives app restarts. Read more about it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities

Comment: Thanks for that but i'm trying to achieve something a little different. I'm effectively trying to mock the backend (Firebase) with a bunch of static json files.